Migrating Ehcache to Jcache with springmodules 0.8x
I am migrating my project from spring 5.x to spring 6.x .While doing this I have been facing issue with bean creation of EhcacheManager since it is deprecated in spring context support 6.x and JcacheManager is now being used. Now, the main issue is I have been using springmodules jar and through that I have been creating bean using EhCacheFacade and EhCacheCachingModel and springmodules jar has not been updated since 2007 so I am unable to rewrite the code for Jcache.
Any inputs will be helpful ,thanks !
Adding the infra.xml code for reference -->
<!-- <bean id="ACacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </bean> -->
    
    <!-- Spring Modules Provider Facades -->
    <bean id="cacheProviderFacade" class="org.springmodules.cache.provider.ehcache.EhCacheFacade">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ACacheManager"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Spring Modules Cache Model -->
    <bean id="cachingModel" class="org.springmodules.cache.provider.ehcache.EhCacheCachingModel">
        <property name="cacheName" value="PBSQueryNameCache"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Properties Factory Bean -->
    <bean id="queryPropertiesFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:QueryData.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:QueryData-extn.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- A Query Cache Providers -->
    <bean id="AQueryCacheProvider" class="com.example.persistence.AQueryCacheProvider" init-method="init">
        <property name="cacheProviderFacade" ref="cacheProviderFacade"/>
        <property name="cachingModel" ref="cachingModel"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="queryPropertiesFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>
    

Now, I have changed this EhCacheManagerFactoryBean and have re-written it with jcache -->
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="ACacheManager"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="ACacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManagerUri" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean>

I need help with re-writing the springmodules part so that ultimately "AQueryCacheProvider" bean gets created.
I tried various solutions given on stackoverflow like adding ehcache jar, using @ComponentScan and more but the issue is not solved. Issue is following -->
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'AHibernateUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ACacheProvider': Error creating bean with name 'AQueryCacheProvider' defined in URL , Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheProviderFacade' while setting bean property 'cacheProviderFacade'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4438)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4876)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1961)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AQueryCacheProvider' defined in URL : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheProviderFacade' while setting bean property 'cacheProviderFacade'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710)
        ... 57 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheProviderFacade' defined in URL : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ACacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 70 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ACacheManager' defined in URL : No CachingProviders have been configured
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 80 more
    
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AQueryCacheProvider' defined in URL : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheProviderFacade' while setting bean property 'cacheProviderFacade'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710)
        ... 57 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheProviderFacade' defined in URL : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ACacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 70 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ACacheManager' defined in URL : No CachingProviders have been configured
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 80 more
    Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: No CachingProviders have been configured
        at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:391)
        at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:361)
        at javax.cache.Caching.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:151)
        at org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
        ... 87 more
20-May-2024 16:17:33.261 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.example.service.ContextListenerImpl]
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.security.SessionRegistryItemManager.removeSessionByHostName(String)" because "this.manager" is null
        at com.example.service.ContextListenerImpl.contextDestroyed(ContextListenerImpl.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4484)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:242)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1961)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)

